# Column not found on COUNT LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i'm trying to search user with join introducing company, and count total topup transaction with the following code

```
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('a.Id, a.UserName, a.Name, a.Sex, a.DOB, a.Email, a.ContactNo, a.Credit, a.EmailVerified, a.Level, a.CreatedTime, a.Active, a.Referral, a.ReceivedFirstTimeDepositBonus, b.Name AS ReferralName, COUNT(c.Id) AS TransactionCount')->from('user a')->leftJoin('company b', 'a.Referral=b.Id')->leftjoin('transaction c', 'a.Id = c.UserId')->group('a.Id');

$data = $data->andWhere('a.Role = 0');
$data = $data->andWhere('c.TransactionCount > 0');
$data = $data->queryAll();
```

but yii throw me error like this

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.TransactionCount' in 'where
>   clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT a.Id, a.UserName,
>   a.Name, a.Sex, a.DOB, a.Email, a.ContactNo, a.Credit, a.EmailVerified,
>   a.Level, a.CreatedTime, a.Active, a.Referral,
>   a.ReceivedFirstTimeDepositBonus, b.Name AS ReferralName, COUNT(c.Id)
>   AS TransactionCount FROM `user` `a` LEFT JOIN `company` `b` ON
>   a.Referral=b.Id LEFT JOIN `transaction` `c` ON a.Id = c.UserId WHERE
>   (a.Role = 0) AND (c.TransactionCount > 0) GROUP BY `a`.`Id` ORDER BY
>   `Id` LIMIT 20

and i try to look at the query for long time, but i cant see what is the problem i don't know why it will throw me error ,even i try

```
$data = $data->andWhere('TransactionCount > 0');
```

but get the same error just column name differrent

Comment: You can not use the column alias in the where condition. More over aggregate function without group by returns just one row. You may use `having` if you want the alias to be used as condition.

Comment: `TransactionCount` is not a column from table c. use `COUNT(c.Id) ` instead in your where statement.

Comment: Ok I see you have `group by` clause, you can use `having` clause if you want the alias to be used as condition

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thanks, after using having it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use aliases in `WHERE` clauses.

Replacing

```
$data = $data->andWhere('c.TransactionCount > 0');
```

with

```
$data = $data->having('COUNT(c.Id) > 0');
```

or

```
$data = $data->having('TransactionCount > 0');
```

should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, learned something, but the fix is
$data = $data->having('COUNT(c.Id) > 0');

Comment: Both should work (didn't test). Using having you can use the alias as well.

Comment: the first one wont work, error 1111 Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0):

Your `TransactionCount` is not real column, but product *after* query execution. That is why SQL can't found it.

Replace `c.TransactionCount > 0` with `COUNT(c.Id) > 0`
Or better use `HAVING TransactionCount > 0`. [In Yii having](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#having()-detail) will looks like `->having('TransactionCount > :desiredCount', [':desiredCount' => 0])`

Comment: `->having('TransactionCount > :desiredCount'), [':desiredCount' => 0]);` will have the following error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TransactionCount' in 'having clause'.` but `->having('COUNT(c.Id) > :ts', array(':ts' => 0));` work

Answer (score 0):

Where cluase always execute before group_by --aggregate function

SELECT a.Id, a.UserName, a.Name, a.Sex, a.DOB, a.Email, a.ContactNo, a.Credit, a.EmailVerified, a.Level, a.CreatedTime, a.Active, a.Referral, a.ReceivedFirstTimeDepositBonus, b.Name AS ReferralName, COUNT(c.Id) AS TransactionCount FROM user a LEFT JOIN company b ON a.Referral=b.Id LEFT JOIN transaction c ON a.Id = c.UserId WHERE (a.Role = 0) AND (count(c.Id) > 0) GROUP BY a.Id ORDER BY Id LIMIT 20